# En/Decryption using Perl Crypt::CBC leads to missing bytes at the end

Tags: perl, encryption, file-handling, des

i am trying to encrypt and then decrypt a file using Crypt::CBC in perl. When decrypting my ciphertext after encrypting it, i am missing some bytes at the end of my recovered plaintext.

encryption method:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.24.0;
use warnings;
use Crypt::CBC;

my $cipher;
my $buffer;

   $cipher = Crypt::CBC->new( {'key'             => 'abcdefgh',
                               'literal_key'     => 1, 
                     # 'cipher'          => 'Blowfish',
                              'iv'              => '01234567',
                           #   'regenerate_key'  => 0,   # default true
                              'padding'         => 'standard',
                              'prepend_iv'      => 0,
                              'blocksize'       => 8
                           });

$cipher->start('encrypting');
open(F,"./plaintext.txt");
open(STDOUT,">ciphertext.txt");
  while (sysread(F,$buffer,1024)) {
      print $cipher->crypt($buffer);
  }
close STDOUT;
```

my plaintext looks like this:

[image: plaintext before]

then i decrypt my ciphertext with:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# # entschlüsselt eine datei, http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=252460

use 5.24.0;
use warnings;
use Crypt::CBC;

my $cipher;
my $buffer;

   $cipher = Crypt::CBC->new( {'key'             => 'abcdefgh',
                              'literal_key'     => 1, 
                              #'cipher'          => 'Blowfish',
                              'iv'              => '01234567',
                            #  'regenerate_key'  => 0,   # default true
                              'padding'         => 'standard',
                              'prepend_iv'      => 0,
                              'blocksize'       => 8
                           });

$cipher->start('decrypting');
open(F,"./ciphertext.txt")
  while (sysread(F,$buffer,1024)) {
      print $cipher->crypt($buffer);

  }
close STDOUT;
```

and the plaintext afterwards:

[image: plaintext after]

Comment: Reopening STDOUT like that is an odd way of doing this. Could you try opening a separate, non-default filehandle? I wonder if doing it this way is causing it not to get flushed the way you expect.

Comment: While it may not have an effect in this particular situation, you want interactions with `ciphertext.txt` to be done using `:raw` handles since it's a "binary" file, not a text file (despite the extension).

Comment: Tip: Using a constant IV is *irresponsible* and *severly* weakens your encryption. Let CBC pick a random one!

Comment: ... and prefix the IV to the ciphertext (it has a constant size). But that's the fourth issue with the code above, I guess you (ichtyp) need to read more into file handling and cryptography before continueing.

Comment: @frezik: I'am now using a separate filehandler, which helped me to get rid of problems with CR LF formatting at the end of the lines.

Comment: @ikegami this helped also in the matter of formatting. the IV was chosen for testing purposes only, i would never use this in the final implementation ;-)

Comment: It's called a file *handle*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re missing a call to [`$cipher->finish;`](http://search.cpan.org/~lds/Crypt-CBC/CBC.pm#finish()) after the loop, for both encrypting and decrypting, so you’re cutting of part of the last block in both cases.

> The CBC algorithm must buffer data blocks internally until they are even multiples of the encryption algorithm's blocksize (typically 8 bytes). After the last call to crypt() you should call finish(). This flushes the internal buffer and returns any leftover ciphertext.

You need something like this:

```
while (sysread(F,$buffer,1024)) {
    print $cipher->crypt($buffer);
}
print $cipher->finish;
```

---

(You’re also missing a semicolon at the end of the `open` line in your decryption code.)

Comment: Absolutely correct. However, I guess that (largely) ignoring the return value of the `sysread` call is a bigger problem.

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot :-) 
The missing semicolon was lost on c&p.
Ignoring the return value is not the goal, i was just trying to get the content of the file right. I will continue on this now. Thanks anyway for the hint!